# Django admin site rename URLs to match my language

Tags: django, url, internationalization, django-admin

I would like to customize the URLs for the admin site so they appear in my native language (Spanish). What I want is to use /nuevo instead of /add and so on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is will do what you want.  [ModelAdmin.get_urls()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls)
But the problem is going to be, how do you hook up the new url to the `admin` view?

The default `get_urls()` is in `django/contrib/admin/options.py`, and it has some somewhat complex code to generate the default urls.

```
 def get_urls(self):
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

    def wrap(view):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

    info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.module_name

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$',
            wrap(self.changelist_view),
            name='%s_%s_changelist' % info),
        url(r'^add/$',
            wrap(self.add_view),
            name='%s_%s_add' % info),
        url(r'^(.+)/history/$',
            wrap(self.history_view),
            name='%s_%s_history' % info),
        url(r'^(.+)/delete/$',
            wrap(self.delete_view),
            name='%s_%s_delete' % info),
        url(r'^(.+)/$',
            wrap(self.change_view),
            name='%s_%s_change' % info),
    )
    return urlpatterns
```

What I would do is use this function in each of your `ModelAdmin`s, but change the url text to your language equivalent.

In your example, `add/` would look like this:

```
url(r'^nuevo/$',
    wrap(self.add_view),
    name='%s_%s_add' % info)
```

Note that I left `%s_%s_add` in English.

You can probably wrap this function so you don't have to include the entire thing in each ModelAdmin class.

**Edit**
That code uses a function named `update_wrapper` which is imported like this:

```
from django.utils.functional import update_wrapper
```

I hadn't seen this function before, and I doubt many people have so I thought it'd be useful to point out the import.

Comment: Thanks! This mechanism seems cumbersome and prone to fail. There's no much info in the web about doing this. I'll be careful and post here the results when I'm done.